# I want to print unique strings from a list in python but it breaks the list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am trying to fetch the different file paths through this:

```
for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(imagePaths):
    name = set(imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2])
```

It brings multiple paths that have the same names such as this:
Angelina Jolie
Angelina Jolie
Sam
Sam
Sam

What I want to do is print the unique ones of them. Like print Angelina Jolie only once. But whatever I try whether it is the unique method, or the set method to convert list to a set it returns something like this. And I am not understanding the logic behind this.

> {'l', 'e', 'J', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'o', 'a', 'A', 'n'}
> {'l', 'e', 'J', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'o', 'a', 'A', 'n'}
> {'l', 'e', 'J', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'o', 'a', 'A', 'n'}
> {'l', 'e', 'J', 'g', 'i', ' ', 'o', 'a', 'A', 'n'}

Please help me try to understand why this is happening and what solution should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remove duplicates.

```py
list(dict.fromkeys(imagePaths).keys())
# or
list(set(imagePaths)) # If you don't care about order
```

You don't necessarily have to convert to lists btw.

Comment: I am getting the same result with this as well. I dont understand what is happening.